# nginx proxy_pass для docker хоста

Tags: nginx, docker, docker-compose

Здравствуйте!

Имеется:

1. сервер nginx (за натом, то есть у nginx сервера уже серый ip) 172.16.3.2, который проксирует запросы в локалку
2. docker хост - сервер, на котором крутятся докеры 172.16.3.7.

конфиг nginx:

```html
user nginx;
worker_processes auto;
error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;
pid /run/nginx.pid;

# Load dynamic modules. See /usr/share/nginx/README.dynamic.
include /usr/share/nginx/modules/*.conf;

events {
    worker_connections 1024;
}

http {
    log_format  main  '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
                      '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
                      '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';

    access_log  /var/log/nginx/access.log  main;

    sendfile            on;
    tcp_nopush          on;
    tcp_nodelay         on;
    keepalive_timeout   65;
    types_hash_max_size 2048;

    include             /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type        application/octet-stream;

    # Load modular configuration files from the /etc/nginx/conf.d directory.
    # See http://nginx.org/en/docs/ngx_core_module.html#include
    # for more information.
    include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;

    server {
        listen       80;
        listen       [::]:80;
        server_name  mydomain.net 172.16.3.2;
        #return 301 $scheme://mydomain.net$request_uri
        #server_name  _;
        root         /usr/share/nginx/html;

        # Load configuration files for the default server block.
        include /etc/nginx/default.d/*.conf;
        error_log /var/log/nginx/error_gitlab.log;
        location / {
            proxy_redirect off;
            proxy_set_header Host $host;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $host;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Server $host;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_pass http://172.16.3.7:80/;
        }

        error_page 404 /404.html;
            location = /40x.html {
        }

        error_page 500 502 503 504 /50x.html;
            location = /50x.html {
        }

        listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
        ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/mydomain.net/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
        ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/mydomain.net/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
        include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot


        if ($scheme != "https") {
            return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
        } # managed by Certbot

    }
}
```

В папке conf.d пусто.

На докер-хосте соответствующий контейнер прекрасно принимает запросы из инета и возвращает ответы - все ок.

Далее: на том же докер-хосте крутится другой контейнер, который обращается по домену в инете (соответствующий первому контейнеру), попадает на nginx сервер - который по идее должен вернуть запрос на первый контейнер, но nginx этого не делает.... почему?

То есть если кратко и схематично:

Запрос приходит от 172.16.3.7 на 172.16.3.2 на 443 порт (что видно в tcpdump) и должен отпроксироваться обратно на 172.16.3.7 на 80 порт.
Не работает - в tcpdump пусто.

В какую сторону смотреть?

Comment: Покажите весь конфиг nginx.

Comment: Ну и, непонятно зачем ходить в соседний контейнер через интернет.

Comment: Конфиг весь выложил. Смысл в том, что контейнер может быть в другом месте.